# FunctionalInterface with default methods in C#

Tags: java, c#

I have this `FunctionalInterface` in Java which I'm trying to port to C#, but not sure how to go about it. I have been looking into delegates but seem to get stuck on the default methods in the Java interface.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunction
{
  boolean apply(Argument p);

  default MyFunction and(MyFunction after) {
    return (p) -> {
      Argument copyP = new Argument(p);
      boolean applied = this.apply(copyP) && after.apply(copyP);
      if(applied){
        // boilerplate work
      }
      return applied;
    };
  }

  default MyFunction or(MyFunction after) {
    return (p) -> {
      boolean applied = this.apply(p);
      return applied || after.apply(p);
    };
  }
}
```

If I would just need the `apply` method I could easily port this to a delegate:

```
public delegate bool MyFunction(Argument p);
```

However, the point of my code is to chain different `MyFunction`'s together with the `and`/`or` methods and only apply the work if the logical condition is met. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to deal with the above interface in C# it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whole this code can be done as extension methods for `Func<Argument, bool>`

Comment: Your `and` and `or` methods seem to be written very differently, which is quite weird...

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qy1qky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyFunction` should be, as you said, a delegate in C#. You can use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on `MyFunction` to simulate `and` and `or`:

```
// in a static class
public static MyFunction And(this MyFunction f, MyFunction after) =>
    p => {
      Argument copyP = new Argument(p);
      boolean applied = f(copyP) && after(copyP);
      if(applied){
        // boilerplate work
      }
      return applied;
    };

public static MyFunction Or(this MyFunction f, MyFunction after) =>
    p => {
        var applied = f(p);
        return applied || after(p);
    };
```

Also, you might want to consider the possibility of not creating an entirely new type at all. In C#, [`Predicate<Argument>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8) has exactly the same signature as `MyFucntion`, so you could just write extension methods for `Predicate<Argument>` instead of `MyFunction`, and deleting `MyFunction` all together.